# SignalR long poll silently dies

Tags: c#, signalr

I've developed a chat-type application in SignalR and I'm having a problem with MSIE.

Normally SignalR keeps it's long-poll connection open to the server and refreshes it about every two minutes. What I'm seeing is that this XHR call simply dies and does not reconnect -- on MSIE only. FireFox and Chrome are working flawlessly.

I've tried implementing the disconnect event at the client to work around the problem, but it never fires (on any browser), even when I force a disconnect condition. ("$.connection.hub.disconnected = function() { alert('bye!'); };")

Can any of the SignalR gurus out there give me any indication of where to look? At this point my choices are to refactor SignalR out of the system or spend a bunch of time with the source code... neither option is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your app from within Visual Studio or on IIS? I have faced a similar issue when running on Cassini but on IIS it works fine..

Answer (score 0):

If you block the single thread running in Javascript SignalR can't continue longpolling (if that transport was chosen). Don't block the event loop :).

Comment: Does this mean if we use lock in JS / TS code that SignalR long polling will fail in that case too? Is it hte same for WS? Because I didn't understand from the question how the single thread running in JS was blocked.

Comment: I am using await-lock package from npm: https://github.com/ide/await-lock 


First step is to call acquireAsync() - acquires the lock, waiting if necessary for it to become free if it is already locked. The returned promise is fulfilled once the lock is acquired. After acquiring the lock, you must call release when you are done with it.


After acquiring the lock, there is try block to execute and lock is released in finally block.